# How do I put # at the beginning of the words in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two textareas and I tied them together. When you write in the first textarea I want to create automatic hashtag in the second.

How do I put # at the beginning of the words in the textarea?

```js
function countChar(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;
  if (len > 35) {
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 35);
  } else {
    $('#charNum').text(35 - len + ' chars left');
  }
  var txtVal = $('#' + val.id).val();
  var number = 0;
  var matches = $(val).val().match(/\b/g);
  if (matches) {
    number = matches.length / 2;
  }
  var count = $('#cc');
  $(count).text(number + ' word' + (number != 1 ? 's' : '') + ' approx ');

  $('#' + val.id + 'keys').val(txtVal);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="charNum"></span>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" data-validation="length" onkeyup="countChar(this)" data-validation-length="max35" name="post" id="message1" maxlength="35"></textarea>
<span id="charNumm"></span>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" data-validation="length" onkeyup="countCharr(this)" data-validation-length="max42" name="keys" id="message1keys" maxlength="42"></textarea>
```

Comment: You currently have a typo (`charr` instead of `char`) and an error when typing inside the textarea

Comment: Have a read of [mcve].  50% of your code/question doesn't seem to be relevant to `'#'+val()` so it's harder for us to determine where the actual problem is.

Comment: What is error or problem in your current script ? Did you check `console` of your browser ?

Comment: What's wrong with prepending a `#` before your second textarea? e.g: `$('#'+val.id+'keys').val('#'+txtVal)`

Comment: @Shinjo because that only adds a `#` to the start of the entire string, not to each word in the string

Comment: Noted. Either I mistook the question literally or I'm dumb won't "beginning of each words" would be clearer?

Comment: id comes from inside php because it gives error. i fix it

Comment: not knowing what tag means in the forum does not mean that the question I asked is bad. 
I don't understand why they are rating down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prefix all words in your value string with a `#` character you can use a regular expression.

That being said, there's several other improvements you can make, such as using DOM traversal to relate the textareas together instead of hacking around their `id` values, using unobtrusive event handlers, and using the `input` event to capture all changes to the field. Try this:

```js
$('.message').on('input', function(e) {
  var maxLength = 35;
  var $keys = $(this).closest('.message-container').find('.keys');

  var len = this.value.length;
  if (len > maxLength) {
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxLength);
  } else {
    $('#charNum').text(maxLength - len + ' chars left');
  }
  
  var keyText = this.value.replace(/(^|\s+)/g, "$1#");
  $keys.val(keyText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message-container">
  <span id="charNum"></span>
  <textarea class="message form-control" rows="3" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max35" name="post" maxlength="35"></textarea>
  
  <textarea class="keys form-control" rows="3" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max42" name="keys" maxlength="42"></textarea>
</div>
```